# How do I get the mousePosition in form-relative instead of screen-relative?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I would like to start with stating that my "skillZ" in C# is rather basic.

So, I am trying to add a `tooltip` to the selected item in a `listbox`, this will happen when a user clicks on the item in question.

So my inquiry as to if my usage of `PointToClient` is correct, since I think there is where the problem lies. Or am I totally wrong(which probably is the case)?

```
    public void Listb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
        ListBox temp = sender as ListBox;
        Point mouseLocation = Control.MousePosition;
        Form.ActiveForm.PointToClient(mouseLocation);
        int idx = (int)temp.Tag;
        tooltip.Show(DaysList[idx].Elements[temp.SelectedIndex].EventDate, temp, mouseLocation);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `SelectedIndexChanged` is not raised by code but by user clicking on your `ListBox`, the Form containing your list would be the `ActiveForm` and the code is OK, however you have to assign your `mouseLocation` to the returned value from `PointToClient()` like this `mouseLocation = Form.ActiveForm.PointToClient(mouseLocation);` or much simpler `Point mouseLocation = Form.ActiveForm.PointToClient(MousePosition);`

Comment: @KingKing The problem seems to be that the tooltip is not drawn relative to the form, but rather relative to the screen...
According to my output.

Comment: @MarcusWigert You aren't listening to the new values being returned by `PointToClient`, your intended use is correct, your actual use just needs a slight change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tooltips position refers to the input control in the show() constructor, you don't need to care about the main forms location. Just skip the part with "PointToClient" and you'll be fine!